# Why Queue Give me 0 in last display function

Tags: c++, data-structures

```
#include <iostream>
#define size 100
using namespace std;
class Q
{
private:
    int item[size];
    int front, rear;

public:
    Q()
    {
        front = -1;
        rear = -1;
    }
    bool is_empty();
    bool is_full();
    void enque(int num);
    void deque();
    void display();
};
bool Q::is_full()
{
    return rear == size - 1;
}
void Q::enque(int num)
{
    if (is_full())
        cout << "Sorry Enque Is Full !!" << endl;
    if (front == -1)
        front = 0;
    rear++;
    item[rear] = num;
}
bool Q::is_empty()
{
    return front == -1;
}
void Q::deque()
{
    if (is_empty())
    {
        cout << "Q is Empty You Can't Deque From it" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    if (front == rear)
    {
        front = -1;
        rear = -1;
    }
    else
        front++;
}
void Q::display()
{
    for (int i = front; i <= rear; i++)
    {
        cout << item[i] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
int main()
{
    Q q;
    q.enque(1);  // front=0; //rear=0
    q.enque(2);  // front=0  //rear=1
    q.display(); // display fron 0 to 1
    q.deque();
    q.deque();

    q.display();

    return 0;
}
```

When i try to compare my code with another code my code give in the second display 0 but other code give me -1 and he ask me to print -1 if Queue is empty so why it give me 0 when queue is empty and i make condition to reset values it front==rear in dequeue function if anyone give me hand to solve this problem i will be thankful
**The Second code with output -1**
#include

```
#define size 100
using namespace std;
class Queue
{
private:
    int front, rear;
    int items[size];

public:
    Queue();
    bool isempty();
    bool isfull();
    void enqueue(int x);
    int dequeue();
    void dispaly();
};
Queue::Queue()
{
    rear = -1;
    front = -1;
}
bool Queue::isempty()
{
    if (front > rear || front == -1)
        return true;
    return false;
}
bool Queue::isfull()
{
    if (rear == size - 1)
        return true;
    return false;
}
void Queue::enqueue(int x)
{
    if (isfull())
    {
        cout << "Queue is overflow\n";
        return;
    }
    if (front == -1)
    {
        front = 0;
    }
    rear++;
    items[rear] = x;
}
int Queue::dequeue()
{
    if (isempty())
    {
        cout << "Queue is underflow\n";
        exit(0);
    }
    int x = items[front];
    if (rear == front)
    {
        front = -1;
        rear = -1;
    }
    else
        front++;
    return x;
}
void Queue::dispaly()
{
    cout << "Elements in queue : ";
    for (int i = front; i <= rear; i++)
    {
        cout << items[i] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
int main()
{
    Queue Q;
    Q.enqueue(1);
    Q.enqueue(2);
    Q.dispaly();
    Q.dequeue();
    Q.dequeue();
    Q.dispaly();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What did you observe when stepping through your code line by line with the debugger? Any unexpected variable changes?

Comment: i try this but not find the error yet @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: In the `display` function think of the loop condition `i <= rear`... How many times will the loop iterate when `front == rear` (which is true when both `front == -1` and `rear == -1`)? Perhaps you should not loop at all if the queue `is_empty()`?

Comment: You never check whether it is empty, you unconditionally print `item[-1]`, which has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @molbdnilo i know that but this not the problem as the question he ask me to print -1 if it empty so i leave it like that the question what should i edit to make output -1 and why it give me 0 instead of -1

Comment: Printing `item[-1]` is different from (and much worse than) printing `-1`.

Comment: @aschepler which line this happen

Comment: Read the comment from "Some programmer dude" again. Your rubber duck asks what happens when `deque()` makes the queue empty and then you call `display()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should check whether the Q contains elements or not and then start printing.

```
void Queue::display()
{
    if (is_empty())
    {
        cout << "Q is Empty You Can't Deque From it" << endl;
        return;
    }
    cout << "Elements in queue : ";
    for (int i = front; i <= rear; i++)
    {
        cout << items[i] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check for empty case before running the loop to display queue,
because currently you are running the loop for -1 value of front and rear.

```
 void Queue::dispaly()
    {   if(isEmpty()){
return;
}
        cout << "Elements in queue : ";
        for (int i = front; i <= rear; i++)
        {
            cout << items[i] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```